# Help understanding a derivation in a book

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm reading about Pattern recognition and when I read the appendix on my book I came across with the following derivation:

$J(\theta)$ is cost a function with parameter $\theta = (\theta_1, ..., \theta_d)$. If $J(\theta) = c$ then:

$$dc = 0 = \frac{\partial J(\theta)^T}{\partial \theta}d\theta \Rightarrow \frac{J(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \perp d\theta$$

This maybe a very easy question, but the derivation above confuses me...could someone write it out more explicitly what the author did :) I attached a picture showing more information taken from the book. I have highlighted the area I found confusing...what happened in the red area?

[image]

Thnx for guidance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the variable $\mathbf{\theta}$ depending on some parameter $t$.  Then on a level curve,

$$J(\mathbf{\theta}(t))=c$$

we have

$$\frac{d}{dt} J(\mathbf{\theta}(t)) = \frac{dc}{dt}$$

The RHS is zero because $c$ is a constant.  The LHS is, by the chain rule,

$$\left (\frac{dJ}{d\mathbf{\theta}}\right)^T \frac{d\mathbf{\theta}}{dt} = 0$$

The transpose arises because the chain rule dictates it.  Recall that the $d/d\mathbf{\theta}$ operator is a gradient operator; work the derivatives out component by component.  For any two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, the dot product may be written as $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b}$.  Therefore, when $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b} = 0$, we can say that $\mathbf{a} \perp \mathbf{b}$.

"Multiply" through by $dt$ to get the equation you wanted.  (Why is it possible to do this?  It is OK if you consider the derivative as the limit of the ratio of two very small quantities; in this case, a small quantity is $dt$.)

Answer (score 1):

$J=J(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$ is a function of $n$ variables $\theta:=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$. 
Its gradient $\nabla J(\theta)$ is the vector

$$\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta}:=\nabla J(\theta)=(\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta_1},\dots, \frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta_n}),$$

while

$$c=\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta}d\theta:=\langle \frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta}, d\theta\rangle$$

is the differential of $J(\theta)$ at $\theta$. With $d\theta=(d\theta_1,\dots,d\theta_n)$ the author means the vector of infinitesimal increments of the point $\theta$.

The equation

$$c=0$$

is equivalent to the orthogonality of the vectors $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ and $d\theta$ w.r.t. the Euclidean scalar product $\langle,\rangle$.

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: Hi I wanted to ask about your answer on this post :) You said that $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta}d\theta$ is the differential of $J(\theta)$ at $\theta$. Isn't $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta}d\theta$ the same here as $\frac{dJ(\theta)}{d\theta}d\theta$? I just get confused with the notation easily :) I want everything to be crystal clear on my mind x)

Comment: In my notation $\theta$ is the vector $\theta=(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$ of $n$ variables for $J$. Then you compute partial derivatives w.r.t. $\theta$'s, not ordinary derivatives, and the gradient of $J$ at $\theta=(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$ has notation $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}$. Such vector is given in the first formula of the above question. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But does $\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{d J(\theta)}{d \theta}$ in my example? Because I'm taking the derivative w.r.t to the vector $\theta$, not a spesific value in the vector e.g. $\theta_i$. This is what I'm essentially asking :) For example if $y = f(x)$, then does $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$? You give excellent answers by the way! I need to give you up votes in many posts for helping me out ;D Sorry this might be a stupid question, maybe I just got confused because of Ron's and your answer when I looked at them together

Comment: If you **formally** cancel $d\theta$ at denominator with $d\theta$ on the right, then in your notation $dJ(\theta)$ is the differential of $J$ at the vector $\theta$ IF, when you need to define it, you write $dJ(\theta)=\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}d\theta$. This is correct :)

Comment: Note that $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}d\theta$ is the scalar product $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}d\theta:=\langle\nabla J(\theta),d\theta\rangle$, with $d\theta=(d\theta_1,...d\theta_n)$.